# Load images from sdcard into a grid view and click for full screen - null ppointer exception

Tags: android, gridview, sd-card, android-sdcard

Basically I had a grid view that showed a set of images from the drawable resources but I want it to pull up images from my phone's sd card instead.

I'm getting a null pointer exception for this: **return cursor.getCount();**
and this also: **gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));**

Could anybody explain why its null? I tried to initialise cursor but I was having trouble with that too.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageAdapter adapter;
private Cursor cursor;
private  int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //Toast below states position of image
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Sending image id to fullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);

            //passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public void startCamera(View v){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}




public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
ImageView imageview;
Cursor cursor;
int columnIndex;

public ImageAdapter(Context adapter) {
    mContext = adapter;
}

public int getCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
    //return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    //imageView.setImageDrawable(mySDCardImages.get(position).getDrawable());
    return imageView;
}

        // references to our images
        /* public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};*/

}


      public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    //get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    //selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, cursor);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(position);
}

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a cursor in your adaptor class that never has its value set, so will always be null.  Delete the declaration and use the parent's cursor.

Comment: how do I use the parents cursor?

Comment: By name-  a subclass has direct access to all the variables of the parent class.  But by declaring another variable in the subclass of the same name, you're masking it.

Comment: Sorry I'm just learning this a few months, you'll have to be patient with me. I know what your saying but when I delete the declaration in the Adapter class then cursor has an error that it cannot be resolved. How do I tell it to get the cursor declared in the MainActivity?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You put up two different files there, didn't you?  Ok, there's two ways to fix this.  One is to make the adaptor class a subclass inside of the activity class.  Then it can access the activity's variables and deleting the one line will fix it.  The other way is to pass the Adaptor the Cursor object in its constructor, and save it off.  So you'd change the adaptor constructor to take 2 parameters (context and a cursor), and save the cursor passed in in the cursor variable in your adaptor.

Comment: Yes thank you, I had two different files because I didnt like the adapter inside the mainActivity. So I put this in:     public ImageAdapter(Context adapter, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = adapter;
        c = cursor;
        
    } And it solved the error problem but I have no images being displayed. Am I calling the path to the images folder correctly?